# What is the difference between two keep identity in oledb destination

Tags: ssis

What is the difference between keep identity in OLE DB Destination Editor and fastload   keep identity in OLE DB Destination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are talking about the difference between OLE DB Destination Editor

[image: OLE DB Destination Editor]

and the corresponding property?

[image: OLE DB Destination Properties]

They are the same thing. The second image is what is serialized out in the XML from the object while the former is BIDS/SSDT's representation of those properties. You can verify this by turning either one on or off and observing the same change is mirrored in the other.

Generally speaking, the Properties of an object in SSIS will always show you the unvarnished truth but the listed items may not always be useful or well named. For those items, the SSIS team generally provides customized editors to address or configure components.

Comment: Hi,Then where i have to set for enabling fast load option?

Comment: You may use either the properties or the editor to set the Fast Load option. The `Fast Load` checkbox is a synonym for the property `FastLoadKeepIdentity`

Answer (score 9):

when you use fast load you have the option of keeping your record's identity. So, if you are inserting rows from table A to table B and table B has an identity field, if you check "keep identity", it will ignore the identity generation rule on table B and insert the identity values on table A.

Example (assuming table B is empty with an ID identity(1,1) field:

```
TableA ID's   TableB keep identity off    TableB keep identity on
10                   1                              10
11                   2                              11
12                   3                              12
```